# QGIS Error: Join attribute by location

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, attributeerror

I'm getting this error code with QGIS when I am using the tool Join attribute by location: I'm trying to join the attribute table of polygons into my vector points attribute table.

```
Processing algorithm…
    AlgorithmDialog
    Input parameters:
    { 'INPUT' : 'C:\Users\renau\Desktop\Geocoding_test_batch_Jakarta\3. spatial query on territory\Shape_FILE_UTM8_transformation\batch.shp', 'JOIN' : 'C:\Users\renau\Desktop\Geocoding_test_batch_Jakarta\3. spatial query on territory\Shape_FILE_UTM8_transformation\kelurahan_21148.shp', 'PREDICATE' : [0], 'JOIN_FIELDS' : [], 'METHOD' : 0, 'DISCARD_NONMATCHING' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:' }

Feature (61) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.48 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Join attributes by location' finished
```

How can i fix this error?

I can get also this error:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type AlgorithmDialog has been deleted 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 344, in executeAlgorithm
    if dlg.wasExecuted():
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type AlgorithmDialog has been deleted


Python version: 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.0.1-Girona Girona, a86bec25eb 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/renau/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/renau/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin\python36.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages
C:/Users/renau/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\renau\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
```

Comment: You should check the geometry validity of your layers and fix these before running the join tool. You could try and fix these using the native tool `Fix geometries` or GRASS's `v.clean`. Another option (which is not really advised) is to set your algorithms to ignore invalid geometries. You can set this option from the menubar: `Settings > Options > Processing > General > Invalid features filtering`.